# Invisible character at the end of line using line break

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I need your help,

It appears as though, an extra character or whitespace is added with the regex replace method of:

```
string.replace(/\n/g,'<br>')
```

Is is possible to get rid of this? or is that just the way that this method does that?

Thanks

Comment: How did you verify that `an extra character or whitespace has been added`

Comment: Chances are your new line is a `CRLF` i.e. `\r\n`.  When replacing just the `\n` you're being left with the CR, `\r'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are unsure about whether a single `\n` or `\r` could occur (and either is a valid line end), or possibly in combination with the other, here is a belt-and-suspenders approach:

1. replace all `\n\r` and all `\r\n` combos with `\n` alone.
2. replace all remaining `\r` with `\n`.
3. replace all `\n` with `<br/>`

with

```
 string = string.replace(/\r?\n\r?/g, '\n');
 string = string.replace(/\r/g, '\n');
 string = string.replace(/\n/g,'<br/>');
```

Written out as separate instructions for clarity. Instead of first changing to `\n`, you can also immediately insert `<br/>`s, of course.

Comment: Very thorough. Lots of regex, but it does the job!

Answer (score 4):

That might be the carriage return character `\r`.

Use: `string.replace(/\r?\n/g,'<br>')`

Comment: This would replace multiple consecutive line breaks by only one HTML-Linebreak, wouldn't it?

Comment: Whas the answer edited after those comments? Otherwise the comments doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Nitek, No, it would replace each instance of either "\r\n" or "\n" (without a preceding "\r") with "<br>".

Comment: @BrianS after the last edit it does, before it didn't